# getting mssql queries by writing a middleware

Tags: c++, c, sql-server, middleware

Can anyone please show me the right direction for writing a middleware for mssql server. What I want to do is setup a listener on the mssql 1433 tcp port which will accepts db connections, extract the query and write it on file and forward the connection to a real mssql server on another IP or the same for processing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to know the protocol of communication between MS SQL clients and servers. I doubt it's an open protocol, but I don't know for sure. You should do a research for this. The rest of the work is not a big deal - you need a (simple) socket-based application.

Comment: Be aware, that MSSQL can also use RPC dynamic ports or named pipes.

Comment: Why not just run a [SQL Server trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx)? It's a built-in feature so you don't need to write anything yourself and it can be configured to write to log files with rollover.

Comment: @Pondlife I dont have access to the source code of the web application..can I still use it?

Comment: Did you follow the link I posted and read the documentation? SQL Trace is part of SQL Server and it runs on the server side, so you do not need to make any changes to the application. It 'watches' activity on the server and logs whatever events and queries match the filter conditions you choose, so it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Pondlife Hi thanks for ur answer, this is exactly wat I want, just have to see if I can get it up and running now..btw I want to log each and every query to a specific db instance..thanks anyway :)